# android: onClick responds only to second click in listview

Tags: android, onclick

I found a similar question about scrolling listview and button click but it did not help me. My issue is:

I have a listview with custom rows. I have two different states of listview; the switch between the states is a button at the bottom of the screen. The second state has delete buttons in every row. When I click on delete button in a specific row, that row is removed from database and listview is updated. Everything works great except I need to click the delete button twice in order for it to work. Below is my code for handling the clicks. flag==1 is the second state of the listview.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    View main = parent.getChildAt(position);
    TextView delete = (TextView)main.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);

    if(flag==0){
        switchToItemsView(id);
    }
    if(flag==1){
        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mDbHelper.deleteList(id);
                        updateListView();
                    }});
    }
}
```

I tried to set parent view's focusableInTouchMode attribute to false as suggested in another post but it did not help.

If you can help me solve this I will be grateful,

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending hours I figured out how to do it:

I moved my click listener from my main activity class to my custom ListAdapter class and modified it a little like below;

```
deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int rowid = Integer.parseInt(rowIds.get(position));
        mDb.deleteList(rowid);
        lists.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Now it works great. When I click delete button it removes the list both from the ArrayList (the one used in ListAdapter) and from database.

Answer (score 7):

Probably you have focus. Remove it.

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the `onClickListener` before the actual flag check; in your case the view changes and with that the flag, and the listener is set. The next click actually triggers the listener.

Not related, but you should change your second `if` to an `elseif` since there is no way it would be called if the first one is called.

Comment: I don't think it is because of flag. When I remove both flags I still need to click twice :( –

Comment: Try declaring it outside of the `onItemClick`-method? In your `onCreate` if possible.

Comment: I tried that too but I have to declare it inside listview's clicklistener method, otherwise it throws an exception for not finding the delete button by id. Thanks anyway

Comment: I guess that's because the main layout hasn't been inflated. I'm not sure what your code looks like, but if at all possible try inflating it in the `onCreate` and then adding the `onClickListener` for the delete button.